# Stop inherit method in abstraction

Tags: c#, abstraction

I have an abstract class that has it's inherits. in the parent method, I check some conditions and if they happen, Child method should stop running. But after `return` the child is continuing it's codes! The methods should be void.
Also I tried `throw new Exception();` but not working.

```
public abstract class ParentClass
{
    public virtual void Method()
    {
        if (true)
        {
            // do something
            Console.WriteLine("Parent Method should stop it's child!");
            return; /* So the child should be stopped to call it's things*/
           // Also checked by throw exception.
        }
    }
}
```

And in `ChildClass`

```
public class ChildClass :ParentClass
{
    public override void Method()
    {
        base.Method(); // Also checked by try/catch
        Console.WriteLine("Should't be run");
    }
}
```

So how can I do like so (parent control the child process to continue or not)?

Comment: Overriding means the child can do whatever they want. They don't even *need* to call `base.Method()`. You probably should expose a protected getter/method which returns whether or not the child needs to do work.

Comment: Why do you think your child method shouldnt be called? You are just exiting the parent method, the child method gets called anyway.

Comment: The `return` statement only returns from the current method, so in your case from the one declared by the `ParentClass`. But this will not stop any further statements being executed in the calling method (`ChildClass.Method()`).

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking for a way to do so!

Comment: throw an excpetion from base

Comment: Well.. you could throw an exception, or you could make the method return `bool` and make the child only continue when the `base.Method()` call returned `true`.

Comment: _"I tried throw new Exception(); but not working"_ -- really? why not? you are saying that, with the code example above, when you throw an exception from the base class method, the derived class method still continues to execute? I.e. you see "Should't be run" in the output? That seems unlikely. Please fix your question so it includes a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're trying to do, and why the suggestions here in the comments don't address your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

need to say it's very bad design decision to do it in the way you are doing it, but if you really need it in that way

```
public abstract class ParentClass
{
    public virtual void Method()
    {
        if (true)
        {
            // do something
            Console.WriteLine("Parent Method should stop it's child!");
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}

public class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    public override void Method()
    {
        try
        {
            base.Method();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Should't be run");
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe create a new Exception Type like `PreventFromRunningException` to be thrown from the baseclass. That way other exceptions will not be swallowed, which can result in pretty sick bugs :)

Comment: @LuckyLikey you are right, it's only concept not to make it over complicated  for the starter, we can make it with field or property as well and more and more, as I wrote it's not a good design decision at all

Comment: Yep, I have seen it. IMHO, this is an absolute NO-GO, and a miss-use of exceptions. However your code works, in OP's desire. My Comment was just a slight improvement to at least not introduce a extra source of potential errors.

Answer (score 1):

If we change the Method signature to **Boolean** you can do this:

```
class ParentClass
{
    public virtual bool Method()
    {
        return false;
    }
}

class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    public override bool Method()
    {
        var toContinue = base.Method();
        if (!toContinue)
        {
            return false;
        }

        //Continue..

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a "Template Method":

```
public abstract class ParentClass
{
    public void Method()
    {
        FirstOperation();
        if ( .. some condition ..)
        {
            SecondOperation();
            // do something
            Console.WriteLine("Parent Method should stop it's child!");
        }
        else
        {
            ThirdOperation();
        }
    }

    protected abstract void FirstOperation();
    protected abstract void SecondOperation();
    protected abstract void ThirdOperation();
}


public class ChildClass :ParentClass
{
    protected override void FirstOperation();
    {

    }

    protected override void SecondOperation();
    {

    }

    protected override void ThirdOperation();
    {

    }
}
```

This way you are able to control the flow from the parent object and just invoke the method you need in the child object.